# CSS class conflicting with CSS id

Tags: html, css

first time poster here so go easy. I have an html form with a table in it and I have a seperate CSS file. Before I added in the table everything worked. Here is the html page:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
  <h1>

  </h1>
</div>

<div id="navigation">
  <ul>

  </ul>
</div>


    <div id="content">
    <h2>

    </h2>   

      <div class="scrollableContainer">
        <div class="scrollingArea">

         <table class="cruises scrollable">
          <thead>

            <tr> 
            </tr> 

          </thead>

           <tbody>

            <tr> 
            </tr> 

           </tbody>

          </table>  
         </div>
         </div> 

    </div>

      <div id="footer">

      </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
#container
{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #CCC;
  font-family:"Arial";
}

#header
{
  background: #6C0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#header h1 { margin: 0; }

#navigation
{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #666;
}

#navigation ul
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul li
{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

#navigation li a
{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

#navigation li a:hover { background: #383; }


#content
{
  float:left; 
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 1%;
}

table.cruises { 
  table-layout:auto;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  cellspacing: 0; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  width: 100%;    
  }

table.cruises th, table.cruises td { 
  border-left: 1px solid #999; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999; 
  padding: 2px 4px;
  }

table.cruises th { 
  background: #6b6164;
  color: white;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  width:100%;
  }

table.cruises td { 
  background: #eee; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  }

div.scrollableContainer { 
  position:fixed;   
  padding-top: 1.7em; 
  margin: 40px;    
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background: #aab;
  background: #6b6164;
  }

div.scrollingArea { 
  height: 200px; 
  overflow: auto; 
  }

table.scrollable thead tr {
  left: -1px; top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  }

table.cruises td.operator { background: #ebcb4d; }
table.cruises td.tonnage  { background: white; }
table.cruises td.name     { background: #C7E0C1; }  
table.cruises td.began    { background: #B7C3E8; }

table.cruises .name     { width: 108px; }
table.cruises .operator { width: 126px; }
table.cruises .began    { width: 76px; text-align:center; }
table.cruises .tonnage  { width: 60px; text-align:center; }
table.cruises .status   { width: 160px; }

#content h2 
{ 
  margin: 0; 
}



#footer
{
  clear: both;
  background: #6C0;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 1%;
}
```

Now the table is displayed fine on my page. But it is like the table is just floating in the middle. I believe the problem is to do with the classes and the ids and they are conflicting in some way but I do not know how to fix this. I want it to be between the header and footer but it just overlaps the footer and looks gross. If someone knows why it isnt working that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer met your needs?
FYI, All I did was to paste your code in JSFiddle, then used right click in chrome and 'Inspect Element' (also available in IE and Firefox with Firebug) on the floating table and manipulated the css to see what fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `position:fixed` from your `.scrollableContainer` in your css. It is what causing your table to float.

Here is a JSFiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/wpkaJ/

Here it is after my suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/wpkaJ/1/

Comment: Thank you this does seem to work. However this 'position:fixed' is there so that the table headings do not move. When I remove it, it is just a normal table. Is there any way I can override this perhaps in the 'content' portion of the CSS?

Comment: That is an off-topic question, You might want to close this one and add a new one with your floating table header problem (with less distructive information).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to remember in the future is CSS specificity. It takes 256 chained classes to override a single id rule. Don't use id's unless you have a good reason to, and you will find that some of your problems will dissipate.

http://css-specificity.webapp-prototypes.appspot.com/